# How long "1" is

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, time, sum

I have question to SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have the following data: [SQL Query and Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0Q2y.png)

I am trying to calculate the difference in time between consecutive records where wartosc = 1 and wartosc = 0. I then want to sum this difference for all records.

For instance in my example:

> Row 1 has wartosc = 1 and czas = 2016-07-14 22:01:36 and
>
> Row 2 has wartosc = 0 and czas = 2016-07-14 22:02:06

I would like to find the time difference between Row 1 and Row 2. I would like to do this for all records and sum the resulting time differences.

I add rows when value is changing, now I must subtract time where *0* is to *1*

for example:

> (2016-07-14 22:02:06  -  2016-07-14 22:01:36) + (2016-07-14 22:04:56 
>   -  2016-07-14 22:02:11) + (2016-07-14 22:17:01  -  2016-07-14 22:14:56) ...

Comment: what do You mean by 'How can I check how long "1" is in all records?'

Comment: I have a table which records every status change of an entity

I need to calculate the total '1' time i.e time between '0' and last '1'.
In table i have status of hydraulic and I want to know, how long was '1'

Comment: please explain carefully

Comment: I am trying to calculate the difference in time between consecutive records where wartosc = 0 and wartosc = 1 and than I will be know, how long "one" was. 

I then want to sum this difference for all records.

Comment: Can you group the pairs of records using a key? If not, you'll need to work out the logic for an `ORDER BY` then you can use `LAG`/`LEAD`.

Comment: Sounds like you have a design flaw, that you are trying to query non-relational data (a log?) using SQL. The flaw is having two elements of the same entity stored in the same column(s) on different rows e.g. like storing latitude and longitude in the same column, then writing a query to put them back together as coordinate pairs. Consider using a different tool e.g. Python script?